# Call Symfony Repository method with parameters from array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, parameters

symfony 3.4

I have to call a function

```
$this->em->getRepository($info['repoName'])->$info['funcName']->(//params
```

the problem is that my function has parameters by coma like

```
functionName($param1, $param2);
```

and I receive an array that has values of this parameters in 
$arr['params']
VERY IMPORTANT!
I will not be able to call it like `functionName($arr['params'][0], $arr['params'][1])` because I will never know what function from what repo is used and how many params it has, this all info is stored in yml, taken from there, data is just found in other functions and just passed here. Guys please pay attention at this - this is dynamic, there may be any number of params in array and it is of course the same as in function, but how to call the function when parameters should be specified with coma and I have an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your PHP version there are different approaches. I personally prefer argument unpacking, also referred to as splat-operator:

```
$this->em->getRepository($info['repoName'])->$info['funcName']->(...$info['params']);
```

This feature was introduced in PHP 5.6, see: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Another common approach is to use [`call_user_func_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) where you provide a callable for what method should be called on which object and then an array of arguments. In your case it will probably look something like this:

```
call_user_func_array([$this->em->getRepository($info['repoName']), $info['funcName']], $info['params']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) :

```
call_user_func_array([
        $this->em->getRepository($info['repoName']), $info['funcName']
    ], 
    $arr['params']
);
```

Comment: omg I was around this function trying to work it out,  with the object I was trying to create new and I just had to call it from em, great! thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome. The splat-operator is also an elegant way to code it, if you have the right php version. See @dbrumann response